# Background changes while using transform()

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transform

I have this test setup. When I hover over the "Block 1" it should get transformed while keeping its integrity. What I see is that background color is changing. It seems like it's all about background of that *.blocks:after* element. 
(if I comment that, background of element won't change while hovering over).

So, what could cause a problem?

Source - https://jsfiddle.net/1k5e2090/6/

```
body {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 55px;
  margin: 25px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.blocks#block1 {
  background: #4BACC6;
  left: 500px;
  top: 200px;
}

.blocks#block2 {
  left: 500px;
  top: -50px;
  background: #9BBB59;
}

.blocks#block3 {
  left: 200px;
  top: -45px;
  background: #C0504D;
}

.blocks:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: #F2F2F2;
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  right: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.blocks#block1:after {
  box-shadow: 3.5px 5.5px 1px -1px rgba(75, 172, 198, 0.45);
}

.blocks#block2:after {
  box-shadow: 3.5px 5.5px 1px -1px rgba(155, 187, 89, 0.45);
}

.blocks#block3:after {
  box-shadow: 3.5px 5.5px 1px -1px rgba(192, 80, 77, 0.45);
}

.blocks#block1:hover {
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: translate(-100px);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `:after` behavior on `.blocks` elements. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1k5e2090/8/)

```
 .blocks:hover:after { border: 6px solid #fff; background: transparent;  z-index: -2;  }
```

Comment: This one actually works with original :after (over-complicated) borders though feels like a hack. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome ! Yes, I didn't change the original code but it can surely be simplier than that using border and box-shadow, as @Abhijeet said

Answer (score 1):

```
.blocks {
  border: 7px solid #f2f2f2;
}
```

i have edited your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1k5e2090/9/

you have used the border as a :pseudo element which is not necessary. it is actually creating the problem

Comment: Indeed, apparently there was no need for :after borders. Thanks!

Comment: you could mark the best answer for the future reference

Answer (score 1):

In place of using before and after use simple border on blocks and gives box shadow, This is happened because you use position absolute in before and after so when a block moves before and after adopt automatically.Hope it work
Simple use border around the block and remove before and after your problem will solved

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. Thx!